# Struggle creating correct physicsbody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my current project I create some node that I would like to create physics bodies for.
This creates the nodes:

```
let seg = SKShapeNode(ellipseOf: CGSize(width: 10 / xScale, height: 10 / yScale))
let offset = (seg.frame.height / 1.5) * CGFloat(i + 1)
seg.position = CGPoint(x: anchorPoint.x, y: ((size.height / 2) / yScale) + (10 / yScale) - offset)

segments.append(seg)
addChild(seg)
```

And this is how I currently try to create the bodies:

```
seg.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10 / xScale / yScale / 2)
```

I dont know how I would go about creating the correct one. It should function like a normal physics body(edge based bodies don't collide with stuff).

Currently when the circles roll down it looks like this although they are initially circles:
[image]

Also they look very pixelated. Do you have any idea why?

Thanks for your help!